# Regarding AES128bit-CBC

Tags: linux, security

I'm trying to develop a kind of security program on Linux. So, My plan is currently to use AES128bit-CBC. I heard AES 128 is basically supported on OSX. Is there any libraries on Linux like that?

Comment: What kind of security program? Disk (and disk image) encryption can already be done by the kernel on both OS X and Linux.

Comment: It's kind of web security program. While a program accesses with web-sever, setting file will be downloaded. I will make encrption about setting file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libcrypto` library in the OpenSSL package supports AES128 encryption. Most Linux distributions like RHEL, SuSE and ubuntu come with OpenSSL.

The `AES_set_encrypt_key()` and `AES_cbc_encrypt()` functions from `<openssl/aes.h>` implement the function you're after.